# Python cgi.FieldStorage() is empty on form submission

Tags: python, apache2, cgi

I have the following directives in my Apache 2 virtual host configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www/foo_test>
  Options MultiViews +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .py
  AllowOverride All 
</Directory>
```

I have the following simple form HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="foo.py" method="post" id="foo_form">
      <input type="text" id="foo" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is `foo.py`, the executable script that is called when the form is submitted:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
arguments = cgi.FieldStorage()

print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
print repr(arguments)
```

When I submit the form, I get the following response:

```
FieldStorage(None, None, [])
```

There is nothing in the `FieldStorage` object instance that contains values for the fields specified in the form `foo_form`.

If I replace the Python script with a Perl script and its `CGI` module, along with changing the Apache directives to handle Perl CGIs, I have no problems reading fields out of the form. This suggests to me that my Apache setup is okay.

However, am I missing something with instantiating the `cgi.FieldStorage()` object, or with my Apache setup, that is causing the form submission to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the input a `name` attribute if you want its data to be submitted in the form.

Answer (score 0):

It blew my mind, but this is what happened to me.

Apparently you cannot "pull" the information from `cgi.FieldStorage` more than once ?

Run from any `console` tab in a browser:

```
$.post('/api/save.cgi', {'hello': 'world'}, (response) => {
   console.log("DONE");
});
```

Python code in backend

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cgi

fcgi = cgi.FieldStorage()
sys.stderr.write("try 1 %s \n" % fcgi)

fcgi = cgi.FieldStorage()
sys.stderr.write("try 2: %s \n" % fcgi)
```

See error log:

```
try 1: FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('hello', 'world')])
try 2: FieldStorage(None, None, [])
```